# How to show next and previous month names in datepicker instead of just arrows <,>

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

This is my code: https://codepen.io/bskousen/pen/osEJi

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });
```

I want to show next and previous month names instead of <,>. Is this possible in Jquery datepicker? If it is not possible then is it possible in any other datepicker like Bootstrap datepicker?

Any plugin is fine and I am not very rigid on using Jquery datepicker.

Comment: In jQuery Datepicker, you can display month names on next/prev icons as title which is a built-in functionality of Datepicker. But, if you want to replace icons completely with the names then you have to write your own function to set prev/next month names in .ui-icon

Comment: I said I was going to search for a better solution. Here it is, the same as Adeel. But I've updated my answer anyway, because we can achieve much better styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added `navigationAsDateFormat` to get month names which is a built-in feature of Datepicker (but those names can be appeared only in tooltip), but after some tweaking to your Codepen I'm able to display names instead of icons.

jQuery

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    navigationAsDateFormat: true,
    nextText: 'MM',
    prevText: 'MM'
});
```

CSS

```
.ui-icon {
    text-indent: 0;
    color: #000;
    width: 70px;
    background: 0 !important;
}
```

Please check this [Simple jQuery date picker (replace icons with month names)](https://codepen.io/Adeel91/pen/BxmQJw)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

As I said, I've been looking for a better solution.
And I found basically the same as Adeel.

But, you can make more style modifications to get to something where texts fits correctly.
Here is the snippet I ended up with:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    navigationAsDateFormat: true,
    nextText: 'MM',
    prevText: 'MM'
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}


.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next {
  width: 4em !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-title > span {
  font-size: .85em !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev > span, .ui-datepicker-next > span {
  text-indent: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  text-align: center;
  height: inherit !important;
  width: inherit !important;
  background: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  transform: translateY(-25%);
  font-size: .65em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="container">
  <p>This is a datepicker example using jquery, jquery ui, and jquery css</p>
  <form>
    Date:
    <input id="datepicker">
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

---

**Old answer**

I am not aware of any easy way to change the next and previous icons into month names in the jQueryUI datepicker.

But, there is a built-in functionality to show the month in the tooltip instead of "previous" and "next".
Here it is:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    navigationAsDateFormat: true,
    nextText: 'MM',
    prevText: 'MM'
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="container">
  <p>This is a datepicker example using jquery, jquery ui, and jquery css</p>
  <form>
    Date:
    <input id="datepicker">
  </form>
</div>
```

I'll look for a better solution.

Anyway, I hope it helps.